# Why start external java process via shell

Tags: java, shell, cmd, external

When people start external programs from Java, I sometimes see them doing it via "cmd.exe /c my.exe" instead of doing it directly. Why?

Comment: With these informations this question is not answerable. Please provide a concrete example at least with the full code to get the `String cmd` or `String[] cmds` for use in  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds)`.

Comment: Why? The question is abstract. You either call my.exe or do it via cmd.exe /c, for whatever reason.